# Button behaviour

Tags: python, tkinter

I work with Python 3.5 and TKinter.
I defined a label and file dialog that updates this label.
A button is responsible to launch this dialog.

```
self.sel_folder_val = the label that will be updated.
The code:
self.sel_folder_val['text']=filedialog.askdirectory()
```

After pressing the button in order to launch this dialog, the button stays pressed. Any dialog that a button is responsible to open cause the button to stay low (*pressed)* after closing this dialog.
I have tried this also with no help...:

```
self.select_folder_btn.config(relief=RAISED)
```

Code example:

```
self.select_folder_btn = Button(self.top)
self.select_folder_btn.place(relx=0.07, rely=0.57, height=34, width=187)
self.select_folder_btn.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(font=self.font3)
self.select_folder_btn.configure(foreground="#000000")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(highlightcolor="black")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(pady="0")
self.select_folder_btn.configure(text='''Select destination folder''')
self.select_folder_btn.bind('<Button-1>',self.update_folder_value)

def update_folder_value(self,event):
    self.sel_folder_val['text']=filedialog.askdirectory()
return
```

After executing update_folder_value() function, self.select_folder_btn stays down.

Comment: Please post an entire minimal example of code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @kabanus code was added.

Comment: For one, don't use `bind` on buttons. Use the `command` option and let tkinter worry about the event bindings.

Answer (score 1):

First for future reference this is a minimal working example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog as filedialog

class app:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = Tk()
        self.select_folder_btn = Button(self.top)
        self.select_folder_btn.place(relx=0.07, rely=0.57, height=34, width=187)
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        #self.select_folder_btn.configure(font=self.font3)
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(pady="0")
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(text='''Select destination folder''')
        self.select_folder_btn.configure(command=self.update_folder_value)
        self.sel_folder_val = {}
        self.top.mainloop()

    def update_folder_value(self):
        self.sel_folder_val['text']=filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.top.update_idletasks() 
app()
```

and even that's not minimal. Second your problem is hard to find since this isn't minimal- you're doing something **really** weird - binding the button to a click. You're overriding the built-in binding, and apparently it still affects the state of the button on press, but not going back. What you wanted is:

```
self.select_folder_btn.configure(command=self.update_folder_value)
```

instead of your:

```
self.select_folder_btn.bind('<Button-1>',self.update_folder_value)
```

You could also define that in the `Button` command. What you did is bypassed the button mechanism, so apparently only half of it is executed, and the relief is not raised. Note you have to remove the event parameter your method accepts.

Comment: I think your example would be a little better if you removed the use of `lambda`. `lambda` is used too often, and confuses a lot of beginners.

Comment: Oops, it's even not 'classy' to put it here - note the line below is without it. Don't know why I put it in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I used the command:

```
self.select_folder_btn.configure(command=self.update_folder_value)
```

Instead of bind:

```
self.select_folder_btn.bind('<Button-1>',self.update_folder_value)
```

It solved my problem.
Thanks